# Prime generating function

Tags: code-golf, primes

## Background

The Python code

```
((((((((n%35)^11)*195)|53)&181)+n)%168)*n)+83
```

produces 74 distinct primes for \$0 \le n \le 73\$. This code also works in Java. The operators are as follows:

- `+` is addition
- `*` is multiplication
- `%` is modulus
- `&` is bitwise AND
- `|` is bitwise OR
- `^` is bitwise XOR

The produced primes are: `83, 97, 113, 251, 311, 173, 197, 503, 571, 281, 313, 787, 863, 421, 461, 1103, 547, 593, 1361, 1451, 743, 797, 1733, 1831, 1931, 1033, 1097, 2243, 1231, 1301, 1373, 2687, 1523, 1601, 3041, 3163, 1847, 1933, 3541, 3671, 2203, 2297, 4073, 4211, 2591, 2693, 4637, 4783, 3011, 3121, 5233, 3347, 3463, 5701, 5861, 3823, 3947, 6353, 6521, 6691, 4463, 4597, 7213, 4871, 5011, 5153, 7937, 5443, 5591, 8501, 8693, 6047, 6203, 9281`.

## Task

Given an input integer \$n\$ output one of the primes from the above list, such that every output is distinct.

## Rules

- \$n\$ will be between 0 and 73, inclusive.
- You can receive input through any of the standard IO methods.
- Leading zeroes are not allowed in output.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: These primes are generated with consecutive values of \$n\$ but are not consecutive themselves.

Comment: @Arnauld yes that is correct.

Comment: In the unlikely event that it would lead to a shorter solution, it might be worth allowing to output the primes in a different order (e.g. n = 0 ~> 2243).

Comment: @Arnauld ok I will allow that.

Answer (score 10):

## x86 Machine Code, 23 bytes

```
86 89 C8 D4 23 34 0B 6B C0 C3 0C 35 24 B5 00 C8 D4 A8 F6 E1 83 C0 53 C3
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZPJTsMwFEX3/oonqiKGthBCoYDCjrIDJFhWIMdxUyPbiWIXDOLbCXbIaPDiLU7um64drBQVMf@YpoSUMyY15S/qQ2psQGZ5QdfMlLdU0gJreqc3DwUT9BJBfUT2ZiPFZgKUmBZjLGwM59A/I8AcxlEPXwHeQOTwkaVttskKV4NPIAiG2c@RRa2OiS1vmrswPQsqnQFbdM/KDyC4mO@3@qpsVXceDut@RRZ108uk6b8IBrrdyKFOmDRCwocFDyOLPDuCs8V/dnS4b4elncluzX6LOr23J@H73lSVI4twILdTLUI0qhF5Tyj4Z@QS3RAG9hRL5ZQaTWUyAazUVjCZgqMQMw1MwXHXtaC6nKU8izkIzCRCLl56d0pjd1exQU9Z/ucRkfpbgwnmdmX/7fWzPs3vmtigFudbtam290nsk/vl8vHmCZZZIbB@1IXXOC/sz7D2XVW5fRUnXTsmCQyLE5E3m56ftvRVOq/t2si3pH6@fSMRaof6dWmGFWGfsDNO9AYqG1Y6ul7pcbKSO6j8JmuOU1VORXjyAw)**

The above bytes of code define a function that returns the \$n\$th prime, according to the formula given in the challenge. The function accepts a single argument, \$n\$, which is passed in the `ECX` register. It returns the result in the `AX` register. (Note: A 16-bit value is returned—the caller is responsible for zero-extending that 16-bit value in `AX` to a 32-bit value in `EAX`, if desired. Add one byte for a `CWDE` instruction if you think that is cheating!)

This is a custom calling convention, but it isn't particularly "weird", and machine/assembly language submissions are allowed to define a custom calling convention.

Credit where credit is due: this code is based on [EasyasPi's x86 submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217201), but carefully optimized for size. In particular, I've chosen to target 32-bit x86 so that I can use the long-obsolete [`AAM` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam), which is not supported in x86-64 "long" mode. `AAM` was designed into the architecture as a way to convert from binary to binary-coded decimal (BCD). To do this, it divides the `AL` register by 10, storing the quotient in `AH` and the remainder in `AL`. (Note that this is the *reverse* of what the `DIV` instruction produces!) Intel's original manuals documented `AAM` as a one-byte instruction, but it was actually encoded with two bytes, where the second byte was 10—the divisor for `AL`. Changing that second byte to another value allows dividing `AL` by an arbitrary value, essentially giving x86 an instruction to divide by an 8-bit intermediate. This trick is used twice, to great effect. (There is also a complementary `AAD` instruction, which allows multiplying by an arbitrary 8-bit immediate value, but that did not result in any savings, since it actually performs the multiplication on `AH`, instead of `AL`, and the shift that is required to support that requires 2 bytes, plus the 2 bytes for `AAD`, which is more than the 3 bytes required to encode the `IMUL reg, reg, imm`.) There are myriad other size optimizations as well, compared to EasyasPi's code.

Here are the ungolfed assembly mnemonics:

```
            ; Input(s):
            ;   ecx = The zero-based index of the prime to generate (i.e., "n").
            ;         (Note: This is assumed to be a value from 0 to 73.)
            ; Output(s):
            ;   ax  = The nth prime.
            ;         (Note: This is a 16-bit unsigned integer;
            ;                caller must zero-extend if desired.)
            ; Clobbers:
            ;   eax, flags
            GenerateNthPrime:
89 C8         mov   eax, ecx       # make a copy of the input (ecx) in eax
D4 23         aam   35             # al %= 35        ; ah = al / 35
34 0B         xor   al, 11         # al ^= 11
6B C0 C3      imul  eax, eax, -61  # ax  = (al * 195)
0C 35         or    al, 53         # al |= 53
24 B5         and   al, 181        # al &= 181
00 C8         add   al, cl         # al += cl
D4 A8         aam   168            # al %= 168       ; ah = al / 168
F6 E1         mul   cl             # ax  = (al * cl)
83 C0 53      add   eax, 83        # ax += 83
98          # cwde                 # eax = ax (sign-extend, assuming sign bit is 0)
C3            ret
```

Note the `cwde` instruction immediately before the `ret`urn instruction there, which is commented out. For the purposes of this submission, this instruction is functionally equivalent to `movzx eax, ax`, which is what the caller of this function would normally use to zero-extend its 16-bit result (`ax`) to a 32-bit result (`eax`). However, `cwde` is encoded in only 1 byte, as opposed to the 3 bytes required by `movzx`. As I mentioned above, if you don't think it's legit that I return a 16-bit result, then add the `cwde` instruction to increase the total size of the function by only one byte.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>38</s>  36 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @tsh*

A slightly size-optimized version of the original formula.

```javascript
n=>(((n%35^11)*6.09&4?13:53)+n)*n+83
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLDoJADADQPafoRtMySJhU/FcPYjSZAGMgpDVg3BjPPvpWbwjvMDdT/3yt1NouRUkqZ0TUBdd37ynflNV@ub54PtRMTilXt@MUbcIg11uhIFAdQeEksOV/nCP4ZACN6WxjV472QC0gohJl3/QD)

Comment: Explanation: Removing `()`s from the original formula gives you a 40 byte answer because the `&` has higher precedence than `|`, however you can exchange the `|53` and `&181` operations to get the same result, at which point the precedence allows you to drop another `()`. Bitwise logic then allows you to change the `&181|53` into `&128|53`, and then the `|53` can be factored into a `+53` outside the next `()`, although the byte count is unaffected.

Comment: `n=>(((n%35^11)*195&128?13:53)+n)*n+83`

Comment: `n=>(((n%35^11)*6.09&4?13:53)+n)*n+83`

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Command Master</sup>

The first part of the code is shorter when replaced by a binary lookup table.

```
•4àт©Á•bsè40*13++*83+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc@7UQNRDIXhVhR7FVjPa2rxOGBnCIgI3AC4Eg8RtOGtgBZoZP3fTDPnG0nn4/q6vr/t@//nd273v9vjd/tiXq/bTx4PFstyOMWy7@ejiqm4SqikSqm0ylA5qbwQzZjcAIYwiGEMZCiDGc5xPvfgHOc4xznOcY5zXOACF/MgLnCBC1zgAhe4xCUucTk/wyUucYlLXOIKV7jCFa5mBVzhCle4wjWucY1rXON6dsU1rnGNG7iBG7gRlyc)

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fc@7UQNRDIXhVhR7FVjPa2rxOGBnCIgI3AC4Eg8RtOGtgBZoZP3fTDPnG0nn4/q6vr/t@//nd273v9vjd/tiXq/bTx4PFstyOMWy7@ejiqm4SqikSqm0ylA5qbwQzZjcAIYwiGEMZCiDGc5xPvfgHOc4xznOcY5zXOACF/MgLnCBC1zgAhe4xCUucTk/wyUucYlLXOIKV7jCFa5mBVzhCle4wjWucY1rXON6dsU1rnGNG7iBG7gRlyc) - 05AB1E has a builtin for conversion to binary

Comment: @CommandMaster I don't know how I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>168</s> 166 bytes

```
.+
$*1¶$&$*
\G1{35}

^((1{16})*)(1{8}|())(1{4})?(11|())(1|())
$1$#4$*8$*1$5$#7$*2$*1$#9$*
\G1
195$*
1{256}

(1{128})?1*¶
$1$'53$*1¶
1{168}

1(?=1*¶(1*))
$1
¶1*
83$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY4xDoMwDEV3XwO3dVwJyYRAGCpGLlFVdOjQpUPFluZaHICLpTYs1rNsv@/va3l/ngV6j7ytAFjPcKJpLvUVkGVb8YwM90mSDxngQSRJuuzYKcT8I2fQZjeSyNFZBRSsWuSoDgxY9ciNYTUcNpAhKElqQqdakzZRJWJP6O0l@D0dLC3qhtB4syEJ73bYVmGI3iSl/AE) Link includes test suite that generates the results for `n=0..73`. Based on @Arnauld's rearrangement that reduces the bitwise or into an addition. Explanation:

```
.+
$*1¶$&$*
```

Make two unary copies of `n`.

```
\G1{35}
```

Reduce modulo 35.

```
^((1{16})*)(1{8}|())(1{4})?(11|())(1|())
$1$#4$*8$*1$5$#7$*2$*1$#9$*
```

Bitwise Xor with 11. This is done by breaking the number down into a multiple of 16 plus optional matches of 8, 4, 2 and 1, adding 8, 2, and 1 only when the corresponding match is absent in the original number.

```
\G1
195$*
```

Multiply by 195.

```
1{256}

(1{128})?1*¶
$1$'53$*1¶
```

Bitwise And with 128 (implemented via %256/128*128) and add on 53 and `n`.

```
1{168}
```

Reduce modulo 168. (No `\G` is necessary as `n` is less than 168.)

```
1(?=1*¶(1*))
$1
```

Multiply by `n`.

```
¶1*
83$*
```

Add 83 and remove the copy of `n`.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
83+]*168|]+181 AND 53 OR 195*11 XOR 35|]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlbK4Qq2CioKJgoGAJAlxcSnrqaQq2VgrqCjpAQSsg1tVTcA7ycftvYawdq2VoZlETq21oYajg6OeiYGqs4B@kYGhpqmVoqBABZBqb1sT@1@RKTc7IV0hT0lYwVDCCcQwUMvXMTf4DAA)

Boring translation of formula.  But nice demo of J's "evaluate right to left / read out loud left to right" property:

- 83 plus input times 168 divided into input plus 181 bitwised and with 53 bitwised or with 195 times 11 xor'd with 35 divided into input.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 43 bytes

```c
f(n){n=('v3ff'>>n%35%31&1?13+n:53+n)*n+83;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJdb9pAEHznV5yQSEwwku/29nyOC32o@isKD8jYCUp7iXCUIiH@et2dhdKmqlRLXu3N7s7MfTTzh6YZhi5L02NaZLdv1HW3y2WaEE/I3tiPlmbpniVM79IsUn0adunVfNvsUjYdHUdGPgDt4aVtXtvtl7VZmGOk3FRlbqyVxLHNDVkJtpSlRYELybgUzEWtyrKMUohBMu8E8wETVhs9RioMk6IelKXHkMqUhFok1CqNhSIFqs6h0TrFqdAIIy5A0LJDNQCnwquZoGwQFTbJiRUP6tfBkXNg9kV5dgucK8QAlz4QqiWOQQSVE1sSKSAEZvJBjwC6HLErinBCFaqBWPLAmAoBzF77PUO3dDgvH@GHlZ8t62FAlz32y@onMvijugqFMqv/So79VOvtNY@b/Z3Etnlq9@frG68On93qUH2Sn8e5@XNN48tc97w3Ga5@l7btQcaK@pJ@kKupzWymq6k5P5JfDyVJpxbqd3AvMB7he7QV9PqydGr9u@FlLy1dNp5szXxpJE76VRK3KTd9ft1Qv1i06wvtafRf58T/dP63lgppVy62z@1XkdPwo@m@bh76Yf79Jw)

Tio link based on [noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9)'s post.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⁺⁸³×θ⁺θ⎇＆¹²⁸×¹⁹⁵⁻｜¹¹﹪θ℅#＆¹¹﹪θ℅#¹³℅5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcyxCsIwFIXh3acIdbmBOMRaqHRSJwdth75AbAIG0sTeJIpPH2up0MnpwM/H6e4COydMSmf7iOEa@5tCGGi1alDbACfhAzQmeihzRlrdKw8DI1MZt1VoBb7hqMNLe3WwEvi2/EG@Lxi5aDvaGdQInI/NyWjc96BGqa0wkK0zSikjy6M/cLI8X@RizrRKaZc2T/MB) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Basically a translation of the original expression, except for the following changes:

- Where possible, the arguments to operators were reversed, to avoid placing numeric constants consecutively
- Otherwise some numeric constants calculated using ASCII codes to avoid consecutive numeric constants
- No bitwise XOR, so calculated longhand
- @tsh's ternary idea on his comment to @Arnauld's answer turned out to be the shortest way to choose between 13 and 53.

```
Ｎθ                                      Input `n`
                       ﹪θ℅#   ﹪θ℅#      `n` modulo ASCII code 35 of literal `#`
                    ｜¹¹                 Bitwise Or with literal `11`
                           ＆¹¹          Bitwise And with literal `11`
                   ⁻                    Subtract, giving the bitwise Xor
               ×¹⁹⁵                     Multiply by literal `195`
           ＆¹²⁸                         Bitwise And with literal `128`
          ⎇                             If nonzero
                                  ¹³    Then literal `13`
                                    ℅5  Else ASCII code 53 of literal `5`
        ⁺θ                              Add `n`
      ×θ                                Multiply by `n`
   ⁺⁸³                                  Add literal `83`
  Ｉ                                     Cast to string
                                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86_64, 33 bytes

```
89 c1 b2 23 f6 f2 80 f4  0b b0 c3 f6 e4 0c 35 66
25 b5 00 01 c8 b2 a8 f6  f2 86 c4 f6 e1 83 c0 53
c3
```

```
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        # in: eax (zero extended)
        # out: eax
        .globl primegen
primegen:
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     dl, 35
        div     dl
        xor     ah, 11
        mov     al, 195
        mul     ah
        or      al, 53
        and     ax, 181
        add     eax, ecx
        mov     dl, 168
        div     dl
        xchg    al, ah
        mul     cl
        add     eax, 83
        ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLhTsMgFIX/8xRkxkRjbdLM6dwz7A2MMQzuWgwFAsx0e/nKaLnd6mJ/lObcy@E7lzLvod2p43PNed/T8SmlDqC@/FEH1lFtrIO97Egu31GpNxRi6eEEzlDoAmgB4vGiwxxCakGprJXZKWqdbKEGTfLHBjta85NW4F1xtTUXhCrocoWykFlGqTMurawpaFX9MWDRoHqfHNqDGttRGg1S62qJMtNiWCNatZ6cmRh0OBci@E3m6nX9LzRv6nzkBUmG4@r2aeuJzkHoZ3NumdTk/ML55tkM442o5VYZY7FuD75JZlMKvJFZOs5UYsPLnPd7eXWDCtjAKaL@4aSlT7Tc@uA@bzjqsEckY@kMSWqeU@De1k7B3l6y/K1hGEiKOaYt44@KiePYCCEJZNBK5rk80cW9KOiC9L8)

Nothing special, it is pretty much a direct translation of the example code.

Comment: [I've outgolfed you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217213)! :-) In large part, I improved on your submission by replacing the `DIV` instructions with the relatively-obscure `AAM` instruction. This doesn't work directly in your submission, since it targets x86-64 ("long" mode), which removed support for `AAM`. I've also made some other miscellaneous optimizations for size.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
I6E6V057]yâ§Z⌠*C++*Zx+
```

Port of [*@theDefault.*'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217162/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/TzNUszMDUPLby8KJDy6Me9SzQctbW1oqq0P7/34DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuCy5LL0IDLyJTL1IDL3BgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
I                      # Push 20
 6                     # Push 6
  E                    # Push 15
   6                   # Push 6
    V                  # Push 34
     0                 # Push 0
      5                # Push 5
       7               # Push 7
        ]              # Wrap all values on the stack into a list
         y             # And join them together: 20615634057
          â            # Convert it from an integer to a binary-list:
                       #  [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1]
           §           # (0-based) index the (implicit) input-integer into this list
            Z⌠         # Push 38, and increment it by 2 to 40
              *        # Multiply the current value by this 40
               C+      # Add 13
                 +     # Add the (implicit) input-integer
                  *    # Multiply it by the (implicit) input-integer
                   Zx  # Push 38, and reverse it to 83
                     + # Add this 83 to the value
                       # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

---

MathGolf doesn't contain any builtins for bitwise-AND, OR, nor XOR. But even if it did, this approach above would still be 2 bytes shorter than implementing the formula in the challenge description would have been:

**24 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py):**

```python
W%A^CE**Wx|G1§&+BD*%*Zx+
```

**Explanation:**

```python
W%                       # Modulo the (implicit) input-integer by 35
  A^                     # Bitwise-XOR by 11
                         # (assuming `^` would have been a bitwise-XOR builtin)
    CE*                  # Push 13, push 15, multiply them together to 195
       *                 # Multiply the value by this 195
        Wx               # Push 35, reverse it to 53
          |              # Bitwise-OR by this 53
                         # (assuming `|` would have been a bitwise-OR builtin)
           G1§           # Push 18, push 1, concatenate them together to 181
              &          # Bitwise-AND by this 181
                         # (assuming `&` would have been a bitwise-AND builtin)
               +         # Add the (implicit) input-integer
                BD*      # Push 12, push 14, multiply them together to 168
                   %     # Modulo by this 168
                    *    # Multiply to the (implicit) input-integer
                     Zx  # Push 38, reverse it to 83
                       + # Add this 83 to the value
                         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 39 bytes

```python
!n=(n+(195(n%35⊻11)|53)&181%168)*n+83
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPViNPW8PQ0lQjT9XY9FHXbkNDzRpTY001QwtDVUMzC02tPG0L4/9p@UUKFbYGVubGXAVFmXklOXkaihoVmppcqXkp/wE)

Comment: You can drop the `*`

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
%35^11×195&Ø⁷+53+%168×+83
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//JTM1XjExw5cxOTUmw5jigbcrNTMrJTE2OMOXKzgz/zc04bi2w4f/)

-1 thanks to the default.

Comment: Sure why not. Actually I don't expect to get much shorter answers...

Comment: 25 bytes: `%35^11×195&Ø⁷+53+%168×+83`

Comment: @thedefault. I almost want to tell you to make it your own answer because it required *actual thought*, but I suppose I was already halfway there (noticing that `53&181` is 53).

Answer (score 1):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 57 bytes

```
[[$2ø\/*-]m:$$35m;!11$2ø~&@@~&|195*53|181&+168m;!*83+.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/z86WsXo8I4YfS3d2FwrFRVj01xrRUNDkFidmoNDnVqNoaWplqlxjaGFoZq2oZkFUFrLwlhbL/b/fwA)

Function that takes a number as input.

### Explanation:

```
[$2ø\/*-]m: {Define modulo function as m (a - (n * trunc(a/n)))}
    $2ø {Duplicate both a and n to have the stack be a, n, n, a}
    \/ {swap n and a and divide, which auto-truncates}
    *- {then multiply by n and subtract a by everything} 
$$35m;!11$2ø~&@@~&|195*53|181&+168m;!*83+. {Prime generation}
    $$ {duplicate n twice because we need to add and multiply by n later on}
    35m;! {n % 35}
    11$2ø~&@@~&| { ^ 11 (xor has be done as (not a and b) or (a and not b) as there is no built-in in FALSE)}
        $2ø {get stack to be a, b, b, a}
        ~&@@ {do b and not a, and rotate twice, stack is now result, a, b}
        ~&| {then do a and not b and or the results together to finish the xor}
    195* { * 195}
    53| { | 53}
    181& { & 181}
    + { + n}
    168m;! { % 168}
    * { * n}
    83+ { + 83}
    . {output resulting prime}
```

Comment: xor can also be done as (a or b) - (a and b) in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 30 bytes

```
+83*%+.&181.|*195x%Q35hT53Q168
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X9vCWEtVW0/N0MJQr0bL0NK0QjXQ2DQjxNQ40NDM4v9/AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n+(((n%35^11)*195|53)&181)%168)*n+83
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADAr3gpdu20mGVCP4nAKEuoNaRDQX@35j7nc22RVfb9kHd3TLMTbIErAOBC6ZEIJXX61QpLMoQFNQYlV@YvMYlbBBbJ8bpAW6M9U@ALPNyI@QM)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 38 bytes

```cs
n=>(((n%35^11)*195)&181|53+n)%168*n+83
```

I just removed all the paracenteses I could.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcuxDsIgFEDRWb7ipbEGiiYSRFFKRyd3F@NCSvKWZ9LihHw7stwz3bAewor1/qUwIqU9tEwQwVfyE@ecem3eSolBXY3YKat@RksSvTrbgaTV1TEWPwvw9gGCh6NrjHA5NaUULLPNc8E0P5Bmvu0yltsr5chRlE44Vuof)

Comment: `4:` should be `311`, not `327`.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!!!

```c
f(n){n=((((n%35^11)*195&128)+53+n)%168*n)+83;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJdawIxEHz3VwTBcqcnXLLZJMfVvpT@impBzrOV0lTUB0H87XZntV8HrpuZ7Owk2W762nWXy7rI5SnPCvnyiPjF2nJsG76zLpUTpkkuRzakcS4nidrzZZMP5mO5yUU5OA2MfAD647bvDv3qeWFm5pSoMk2sjLWSOLaVISvBRllaEFxLxlEwl5SVZUxCpCCZd4L5gAqrGz1KGhSToh6S0aNI20QClwhco7FWpAbrHDZapzjVGmHEBTS07MAG4FR7NRNUDU1FTXJixYP6dXDkHJR9Ha9ugXODGODSBwIbcQ3SUDVxJGkFhKBMPugVoC8nnIoSnFADNhBLHhhVIUDZ637P6Bsd7ssn@GHVZ8t6GejLHudl9ZMY@kldhVqV1X8j135u9fW6t@VuLLHv3vvd9fmG8@OTmx@bR/nxsDJ/1zS81a0/d6bA02cpqVv5u5cnac1E5sVcB@N7OPayA0PW/kN7QX/GJi9@ye1O6HUxHK3M9MFIHO3nWWzkyuyrH6f72axf3CTPg/PlCw)

Simple port.

Comment: Your latest edit appears to be faulty, but see my comment to @Arnauld's answer to see how you could save 2 bytes for real.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -`p`, 43 bytes

```perl
$_=(((($_%35^11)*195|53)&181)+$_)%168*$_+83
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYDCFTiVY1N4wwNNbUMLU1rTI011QwtDDW1VeI1VQ3NLLRU4rUtjP//N@Ay5DLiMv6XX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv25BDgA)